# use jersey2.3 tomcat8 , the page get 404

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

this is pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>

    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.controller.Config</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is Config.java:

```
public class Config extends ResourceConfig {

    public Config() {
        register(User.class);
        register(
                new LoggingFeature(
                        Logger.getAnonymousLogger(),
                        Level.INFO,
                        LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT,
                        LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE
                )
        );
    }
}
```

and finally this is User.class:

```
@Path("/user")
public class User {

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @GET
    public String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and i try all the ways to change the web.xml,but everytimes i get the 404.
and i use tomcat8 servlet3.0,and I try change the web.xml,,but it failed, too.

Comment: What URI do you use to access the resource?

Comment: I resolved this problem,and i find it's idea's bug.the jar hadn't been deployed in the war...